# Status bar text from chrome browser in QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Does any one know how to get the status bar text from the chrome browser in HP QTP/UFT? I know we can access it using Browser.Object in IE but it is not supported in chrome. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

GetROProperty("text") method of WinStatusBar object

Comment: Try to add some more details to your answer. Explain what your code is doing, reference a source if needed.